# Sharepoint workflow: creating a task at another site

Tags: sharepoint

is it possible to create a task in a task list in a site other than the site to which the workflow is deployed to.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope - this isn't supported.  The workflow must be deployed to all sites.

Comment: Hi David
I mean I have a worklfow that starts when an item is inserted in a list in Site A, is it possible to create the task items in a task list in Site B instead of the tasks list in Site A

thanks

Comment: Remember that there is nothing inherently special about a task list except that they are typically tied to workflows. So you can create items in a task list on another site using code. Would the Workflow on Site A need to do anything with the Task on Site B?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about a SharePoint Designer Workflow and not a Visual Studio workflow where pretty much anything is possible.

You can either create a custom Activity in Visual Studio for use in SharePoint Designer or you use something like the [Workflow Power Pack](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/Workflow-Power-Pack-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx) to add a little bit of custom code directly into SharePoint Designer workflows.

Please note that I have worked on the Workflow Power Pack, so consider me somewhat biased :-)